# Rails 4.2 foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, migration

Rails 4.2 newly supports adding and removing foreign keys (in migrations), like:

```
# add a foreign key to `articles.author_id` referencing `authors.id`
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
```

What I don't understand is: How is this

```
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
```

different from this:

```
add_column :articles, :author_id, :integer
```

Thank you for any clarification!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that line:

```
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
```

will actually generates this:

```
ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD CONSTRAINT articles_author_id_fk FOREIGN KEY ("author_id") REFERENCES "authors" ("id");
```

While this:

```
add_column :articles, :author_id, :integer
```

will generate:

```
ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD COLUMN author_id INT(11);
```

Both are different because `add_foreign_key` will add just a [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) constraint, while `add_column` adds a column not a constraint.

Comment: Thanks. So is it correct to conclude that using ```add_foreign_key``` will result in better database performance (because it adds a foreign key)?

Comment: technically, it *decreases* `database performance` as it forces the DB to check this constraint for every update/insert. But it adds `referential integrity` i.e. ensures your data "makes sense", and you don't get inconsistent/orphaned data