# Rails 4.2 foreign key definitions at the migration level when there are more then one reference to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i understand how to define simple relations between two tables as discussed here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model

and here:
[Rails 4.2 foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201054/rails-4-2-foreign-key)

but, how does one define multiple references to the same model in a migration? say for example using the prior posts:

```
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
```

and that you want to have both a reference to the author, and say the editor who is also an author. which would end up with something like this in the model in prior versions of rails:

```
belongs_to :editor, :class_name => "Author", :foreign_key => "editor_id"
```

furthermore is there a syntax for defining this at the rails g scaffold level or would i have to modify the migration after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would just be this:

```
add_column :articles, :author_id, :integer
add_column :articles, :editor_id, :integer
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors, column: :editor_id, primary_key: "id"
```

Comment: with one change this works.  authors pk is "id" so the primary_key: "author_id" changed to primary_key: "id" seemed to do the right thing.  also using t.references for the column in the table definition was fine also